# Как использовать base64 в Vite JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, img, base64, vite

Как использовать base64 для изображений, которые были импортированы в шаблоне Vue путем прописания абсолютного пути? Т.е. чтобы вместо ссылки, было base64 изображение

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Думаю, Вам нужно это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64501373/how-to-convert-image-url-from-server-api-imageurl-to-base64-in-vue-js (vite тут не при чём, это больше инструмент для внутренней оптимизации)

Answer (score 1):

Для Vite.js не находится ничего похожего.
А вот для Webpack есть то, что вам нужно: https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-inline-loader

Именно из-за таких случаев и используют webpack или gulp. Вполне может оказаться, что для Vite просто нет соответствующего лоадера.